# How can I do a PUT with NODEJS sending the complete list with another order to MONGODB

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, updates, put

From my controller in Nodejs I want to send again the list that I get with the 'GET' method but in this case with a different order.
Since when consulting the list the program allows you to move the position records.

I am trying to do a 'PUT; with the complete list to the database but I can't do it

```
//controller update list
listCategoriesCtrl.updateListCategories = async (req, res) => {
  await ListCategories.update(req.body)
  res.json({message: 'Category update'})
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What error message and behavior are you getting? What is in `req.body`?  We need more information to be able to begin helping

Comment: Hello, In the req.body is the entire list of the objects obtained in the db but with another order. but I don't know what Mongo property to use to send the complete list to replace or update the one in the db

Comment: @Gmz01 `update`'s first parameter is usually the `filter` of the query. You should provide more info, like the `ListCategories` schema declaration, the structure of `req.body`, and what packages you are using.